# Installed Raspberry Pi Desktop on old windows laptop. Wifi and ethernet not working

Tags: wifi, ethernet, raspberry-pi-desktop

Very new to this. I had an old laptop laying around and wiped out windows and installed Raspberry Pi Desktop. My Cd/dvd works. Usb ports work. But ethernet and wifi are both down.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I went to raspberrypi,org and got the raspberry pi desktop iso and burned it to a dvd. Used it as a boot disc and installed the OS.

Comment: it is difficult to guess what the problem may be, since we do not know what kind of hardware you are using ..... try running Knoppix live DVD instead

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help because it is not a Raspberry Pi you installed the operating system. It is an intel/amd architecture, not an ARM one. I have not used the Raspberry Pi Desktop but I think it is a default Debian installation just with the RasPi Desktop on top of it. So you should look for troubleshooting on debian installations.

I guess the ethernet and wifi devices on your laptop are not supported by drivers out of the box. Look for the error messages in `journalctl -b`, examine what chips are used for ethernet and wifi, usually with `lspci`. Maybe you need to load firmware to the chips, *journalctl* will show you this. Various firmware packages you will find with `apt list firmware-*`. If unsure what to use look at the details with *apt show*. For example `apt show firmware-iwlwifi` will give you a list what intel wifi adapter are supported by this package.